# How do I subscribe to a liquidity add event?

Tags: ethers.js

I need to subscribe to the liquidity add event on the Binance Smart Chain network using the ethers.js library. How can I do that?

I can only find this example:

```
const filter: EventFilter = {
        address: targetAddress,
        topics: [
            utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")
        ]
    }

    provider.on(filter, async (from, to, amount, event) => {
        // ...
    });
```

But it triggers on any transactions, while I need to specifically track liquidity additions.